# What is Manual Build?

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild

Seems like a pretty obvious question but I haven't been able to find this anywhere online - but what exactly counts as building something manually? As in if I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on Visual Studio is that manually building? Then how could I go from that to automated build (running it from command line?). All I know is that I am supposed to use MSBuild to do automated builds on a project that is currently built 'manually'.

Comment: Usually only a CI system does automated builds. Your definition of "manual" is misleading.

Comment: I don't think I give a definition of manual? That's more of what my question is. As in what consists of manual building and how is it different from automated builds?

Comment: 'running from the command line' is still a manual build since *you* have to initiate it directly. At least, that is how I'd define it. One thing which can be meant with an automated build, is having some software running continuously which looks for when source code changes, and when it changes starts a build (and eventually makes the output available somewhere). Arguably you are still initiating the build since you made the change, but that's an extra layer of indirection, and you don't issue a build command yourself. Search around for 'continuous integration' etc.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is Manual Build?

Whether you are using Visual Studio or MSBuild command to build is considered to be manual build. That because you need to build your project manually every time no matter you are using Visual Studio or MSBuild command. And the hot key `Ctrl+Shift+B` is a quick start mode to build project in Visual Studio.

If you want to automated build, you should consider '`continuous integration'` For example, TFS(Team Foundation Server), Teamcity, etc. You can easily search those continuous integration info on the internet.

The biggest difference between manual build and automated build is that you should manually build your project every time when source code changes, but automated build will execute the build automatically by continuous integration tool when source code changes, no need to build your project manually.